# obtain data from table 2 using reference of table 1 [sql-server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

[TRN_ID] is the id of another table, how to get the data from that table and show this data in the xml output

```
  SELECT TOP (1) [ECB_ID] as Id
 ,[ECB_PASSWORD_GENERATED] as clave
 ,[ECB_CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER] as consecutive
 ,[ECB_BILL_DATE] as  date
 ,[TRN_ID] <- id of other table
 ,[QRC_ID]
  FROM [crdx_COREDev1].[dbo].[ECB_ELECTRONICBILL]
  FOR XML PATH ('FE')
```

example of output

```
 <FE>
  <id>1</id>
  <pass>0</pass>
  <CONSECUTIVE>0</CONSECUTIVE>
  ....
   --These are the data from the other table.
  <emisor>
   <name>1</name>
   <Copany>myCompa</Company>
   ...
   ...
  </emisor>
 </FE>
```

In summary, I have a table 1 with different data, some of those data are references to other tables, using that reference I want to obtain the data from table 2

Comment: You are assumably looking for a sub-select, again using `FOR XML PATH()`, but this question is very unclear. Please tag with the RDBMS in use (product and version) and try to create a MCVE.

Comment: In summary, I have a table 1 with different data, some of those data are references to other tables, using that reference I want to obtain the data from table 2.

Comment: `[sql]` is not enough... You must tell us - at least -  if this is `sql-server`, `oracle`, `mySQL` or something else (best tag with version). Provide some (reduced!) sample data and the expected result. You might read about *xml with nested rows*.

Comment: sorry is sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested `FOR XML` linked to your `TRN_ID`.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [ECB_ID] as Id,
    [ECB_PASSWORD_GENERATED] as clave,
    [ECB_CONSECUTIVE_NUMBER] as consecutive,
    [ECB_BILL_DATE] as  date,
    [TRN_ID],
    [QRC_ID],
    (
        SELECT
            N.YourWantedColumn
        FROM
            YourOtherTable AS N
        WHERE
            E.TRN_ID = N.TRN_ID -- I'm guessing it's called N.TRN_ID
        FOR XML
            PATH ('emisor'), TYPE
    )
FROM 
    [crdx_COREDev1].[dbo].[ECB_ELECTRONICBILL] AS E
FOR XML 
    PATH ('FE')
```